# Caffe make runtest error

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, caffe

I just used make and make test command successfully without errors. However, when I used make runtest command, it failed several times for the same problem.

Though my installed boost is boost-1.55, it doesn't work. The result is as following. What should I do?

```
[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1887 tests from 255 test cases ran. (476334 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1880 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 7 tests, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/0.TestSnapshotShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/0.TestSnapshotShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] NesterovSolverTest/0.TestSnapshot, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] NesterovSolverTest/0.TestSnapshotShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdaDeltaSolverTest/0.TestSnapshotShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdamSolverTest/0.TestSnapshotShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] RMSPropSolverTest/0.TestSnapshotShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>

 7 FAILED TESTS
Makefile:523: recipe for target 'runtest' failed
make: *** [runtest] Error 1
```

Comment: I guess you need to use boost-1.57.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Intel MKL, the cause of this issue maybe: Intel MKL's float point operations (such as matrix multiplication) are non-deterministic by default.

```
    export MKL_CBWR=AUTO
```